# IOS Maps not pinning to map

Tags: jquery, ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap app set up that contains a maps link in it. The link is suppose to exit my program and the enter the maps program pinning the location. But instead the app exits and enters the maps programs but doesn't pin the actual location. I've tried several different locations, link formats, etc. Nothing seems to work. I am running the following:

phonegap 1.4
jquery 1.7.1
jquerymobile 1.1

and a few other things, however I disabled everything and just put a link in an index html file and it did the same thing. Can anyone think of what might be causeing this? Here is the link I am using:

```
 <a href='maps://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino' data-role='button'   class="directions">Directions</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We're struggling with the same issue. This works fine when `saddr` and `daddr` are set (source and destination addresses for routing), but with `q` it doesn't work.

One option seems to be that you set latitude + longitude. But if those values are not available, then there doesn't seem to be a solution (with q parameter, I mean).

Comment: Even with the daddr it doesn't pin the address:    <a href='maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino' data-role='button' class="directions">Directions</a>

Comment: I had it working at one point but I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: I'm wondering if I have something messed up in my phonegap docs? The daddr and saddr pin in maps for you?

Comment: This is the only thing I've found. It uses PhoneGap: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494785/Integrating%20with%20Google%20Maps%20on%20the%20iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link on my comments, the correct query is:

```
maps:q=<search query>
```